# Transfer everything in inventory to Chest

Tags: factorio

Is there any hotkeys or ways I can use to move everything in my inventory to a chest quickly?

Basically I know if you do Shift-Click it moves the selected stack to the chest (or another item that uses the stack).

But if I wanted to move all my items in my inventory to the chest, it is time consuming to manually shift-click everything.

Also, is there also anyway I can use to move every filtered items in my inventory to a chest? (Example: I have 400belts and 100grenades, and I can use a hotkey to move 400belts at once to the chest without affecting the grenades.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To transfer your whole inventory to a chest, **ctrl+left-click on an empty slot** in your inventory. You can also ctrl-click on an empty slot of a chest to transfer the whole content of the chest to your inventory.

To transfer all stacks of the same item type at once, **ctrl+left-click on one of the stacks** of that item type.

Comment: Couldn't comment because of reputation, but I just wanted to point out that the accepted answer didn't work, but the answer by MEW works perfectly (for the "filtered" part of the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Left click a stack. Then hover over another stack of the same type. 
Hold Shift then Double Click

Comment: Hi Mew, welcome to Arqade! It doesn't look like this provides any value over the current answer, nor does it address moving an entire inventory. As far as I'm aware, shift+double click only moves items of the same type, so this would have to be repeated for every unique item in your inventory.